# What's the correct timing for the the starting turbo boost?

Tags: mario-kart-7

In previous Mario Karts, I haven't had any trouble getting the turbo boost at the beginning of the race.  But I can't seem to figure it out in Mario Kart 7 - how do I time the gas to get the starting boost?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To initiate a turbo at the start of the race, hold down the acceleration button right when the number "2" appears, or just a little after it appears.

Comment: For me, the trick was to hit the gas right as "2" was disappearing.

Comment: Yeah it's about half way between the '2' and '1' beeps.

Answer (score 1):

To get the turbo boost, start accelerating when the "2" starts to fade. When it says "GO!" you'll be dashing in no time!

Answer (score 0):

The way I do the boost, is when the 2 almost stops spinning, hold the A button. Then, when the 1 stops spinning, release and immediately repress the A button. This makes sure your kart doesn't overheat and explode. If you time it right, you will get the largest possible boost at the beginning of the race. I have perfected it over many years.